# Looking for a license key algorithm

Tags: licensing, authorization

There are a lot of questions relating to license keys asked on Stack Overflow. But they don't answer this question.

Can anyone provide a simple license key algorithm that is technology independent and doesn't required a diploma in mathematics to understand?

The license key algorithm is similar to public key encryption. I just need something simple that can be implemented in any platform .NET/Java and uses simple data like characters.

**Answers written as Pseudo code are perfect.**

So if a person presents a string, a complementary string can be generated that is the authorisation code. Below is a common scenario that it would be used for.

1. Customer downloads software which generates a unique key upon initial startup/installation.
2. Software runs during trial period.
3. At end of trial period an authorisation key is required.
4. Customer goes to designated web-site, enters their code and get authorisation code to enable software, after paying :)

Don't be afraid to describe your answer as though you're talking to a 5yr old as I am not a mathematician.

Comment: I think the key is "and doesn't require a diploma in mathematics to understand *and isn't so easy to break it is pointless* ", in which case the answer is generally no.

Comment: @GregS. That's the spririt! LOL...I have done some googling, and haven't succeeded in finding a reasonable algorithm. Hoping someone can reference a worthwhile link

Comment: Thank you to the anonymous coward who downvoted the question despite 15 upvotes, 14 favourites, and 21 upvotes on the approved answer. I don't mind that the community moderators have flagged the question as off "as off topic"...

Comment: Though for licensing on my end, I just created a Licensing Server and embedded that in my code with some identification information of the system that would remain static and used that as well as an OpenSSL-generated key to ensuring that the software is validated on that device. Once activated a key can not be used again, and at all startups it ensure's that everything is validated from the server.

Answer (score 56, accepted):

There is no reliable licensing algorithm. Really. Not even one. For the most popular, most expensive proprietary software you can buy, you can also find "key generators" and hacked versions that don't require licensing.

Instead of worrying about making it "unbreakable", just do something simple. A popular mechanism is to, at purchase, ask for the user's name, and then give him a license key that's derived from a cryptographic hash (e.g. MD5 sum) of the user's name, or some variation on it. Then, in the software you ask for their name again, plus the registration key (that MD5-derived thing); you check to see that they match, which activates the software.

Can this be hacked? Absolutely. Once someone figures out how you're generating the license keys, they can generate their own. But if you keep a database of the "official" license keys you've generated so far, at least you'll be able to identify the fraudsters later on (perhaps when they try to download "premium" content or something).

But don't worry so much about stopping the hackers from cracking your code. It's going to happen, but they're such a tiny part of the market that it won't significantly affect your overall sales.

Comment: Name and Purchase date are a common combination.  When they renew, you have to generate a new key.  You record the plaintext name in a file and the file modify time is also part of the hashed string used to create the license key.

Comment: The algorithm would need to also have a way of expiring. Nice idea, but not required for activation in what I am doing.

Comment: @giulio: You don't have to implement expiring.  But you do have to provide enough salt that the key can't be guessed.  The creation date is a standard kind of salt.

Comment: @giulio: to implement expiring, simply encode the start and end date into the product key.

Comment: I have managed to come up with something pretty simple. Basically using TEA ( http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tiny_Encryption_Algorithm )and a combined key uniquely identifying the device. I transfer key info to an authorisation server using base16 encoding. I also including a timestamp if i want to enable a time limit.

Comment: "Once someone figures out how you're generating the license keys, they can generate their own." - only if you screwed up. If your license key includes a digital signature, knowing how it's generated doesn't help the keygen writer in the slightest. They still need to break a digital signature algorithm - an achievement worthy of a scientific publication!

Comment: @romkyns, if you are signing your key with a private key yes that is true, but if you are just hashing a value (emailaddress plus something else) then they can start generating keys for any email address if they have worked that out and the hashing algorithm you are using

Answer (score 9):

I use a system like this:

• create a string from windows licence key + trial period end date

• generate a hash (Sha/md5) from the string

• convert the trial end date to an int (e.g. Number of days)

• the key becomes trial end date + some part of the hash

• convert the key to only uppercase characters to make it easier to enter

ABCD-DEFG-HIJK...

the validation works like

• convert key to bytes again

• extract trial end date

• create string from windows licence key + trial end date

• hash

• compare hash with rest of key

this makes it difficult enough for my audience.

Comment: Thanks. This approach is very similar to what I have been working on. I needed to incorporate a number of elements to make it reproducible and unique to an installation with expiration dates and other information.

Answer (score 6):

The answer is that no, there isn't a secure license key algorithm that doesn't require a mathematical diploma to understand.

The best license keys are the ones digitally signed with an asymmetric encryption algorithm. You sign the key data with a private encryption key and embed the signature in the key, and the key validation (which implies signature verification among other things) is done with a public key. This way, no one can create license keys unless they have access to the private key which is...private. The problem is that there are very few (and difficult) algorithms which have sufficiently short signature sizes to be embedded in a product key. RSA is not one of them (signature size for RSA512 is 1024 bits - too much).

You can check out SoftActivate Licensing SDK it uses elliptic curve cryptography to generate short, digitally signed license keys (C++/C# source code is available).

Comment: Also, if you search for SoftActivate online, you can find keygen cracks for it. That should tell you how useful it really is.

Answer (score 5):

In all honesty, what you're trying to do is pointless. However much time it takes you to write a validation/encryption/key system, estimate roughly half that for someone to break it. Even if you encrypt the final executable. However, as a delaying measure or a way to decrease the chance of people getting premium support for stolen copies, it will help. Also for simple tracking of buyers. Or for fun. :p

Anyway, there are a few ways you can handle it. 
A lot of software uses name (and possibly company) string(s) and a hash function to generate a key. This has the advantage of being constant (as long as the name is the same, the hash is, and so the key is). It is also a very simple system, especially if you use a well-known hash such as MD5.

```
hash = md5(name);
```

Some fancier apps use an internal function to generate a validation code of some sort, and when you combine that and the given name, you can create (and send back) a hash.

```
validCode = getCode(name);
hash = myHash(name ^ validCode);
```

A few use a system-based code (Windows is a good example), where it samples bits of hardware and builds an identifier from that. If you can get ahold of the processor name or speed, or anything else, you can run something like that. The only problem is system changes can render a code invalid, so you can either warn your users (and give away part of the process) or let them find out accidentally (not good).

```
sysID = processor_name() | ram_Speed();
hash = md5(sysID & name);
```

You can use any combination of hash functions, data gets, string inputs, boolean operations, etc. One thing to consider is you don't need to be able to reverse the process. As long as you can replicate it with the same results (any good hash function can), you can check the hashed results against each other and make sure it's valid. The more you put in, the more complicated it'll be, but the harder it'll be to crack.

Hopefully that helps with your question.

Comment: It's worth including a secret in the string that is to be hashed. Any attacker can simply MD5 their own name, adding a secret (and using a more secure hash such as SHA-2) makes it MUCH harder. 

Of course, the secret needs to be included in the software, and can be extracted. XORing it with another string (preferably that looks like it's a string used in the software) will help disguise it.

Answer (score 2):

In matters of security, not reusing a well known and tested algorithm and trying to create your own (lacking mathematical knowledge) is **suicidal**

**Disclosure:** I completely lack the mathematical degree to create such algorithm, and being frank, I don't personally know anyone who has it

Comment: I was aksing for a pseudo algorithm I can adapt into a standard programming language and use the concepts on strings. 

I find it gets "suicidal" if you start tryin to do byte-level translations.

Comment: I *do* have a degree in mathematics with a primary study in Number Theory (where a lot of these sorts of algorithms have their roots in) and I totally agree.

Comment: "not reusing a well known and tested algorithm and trying to create your own "... isn't that why he's asking here?  You know, to avoid doing the thing you are telling him not to do.

Comment: Yes he is just asking how to implement licensing using existing algorithms, not trying to create new algorithms

Answer (score 1):

Since any algorithm you make is going to get broken i would do something simple like this:

```
const string secretMumboJumbo = "sdfkldafskjlfajmkldsfjaewumaskldfladkkldsfklj"

//For you to generate keys
string GenerateLicenceKey(int idNr)
{
    return Sha1Hmac(key=secretMumboJumbo, messageToEncode=idNr)
}

//For clients to check if key is valid, 
bool IsKeyValid(string key)
{
   for(int i=0;i<maxNrOfLicenceKeys;i++)
      if(key == GenerateLicenceKey(i))
         return true;
   return false;
}
```

Maybe the checking could become too slow because it has to try every possible key but that could also be a good thing to avoid brute forcing.

Most frameworks should have an HMAC-function for SHA1 or some other hash function. Worse case you could replace this with md5(key+id)

Don't take this algorithm too seriously, it's just an example and it can probably be broken very easily as the generation-key has to be included in the client, even though it's hidden in the binary somewhere.

Comment: Thanks, I had looked into SHA-1 and found it was a significant performance hit, md5 is an option. I have been researching classes written in pure J2SE. They're not as secure, but the performance improvement is significant.

Comment: @giulio Performance hit? How may keys do you need to generate per second? For the user entering the key it's a one time (or once per load) event. For generating them... well I'd like to be running the business selling software where key generation becomes a performance concern. Many key generation algorithms intentionally perform badly to thwart brute force attacks. However, that performance hit only normally becomes a bottle neck if you are... performing brute force attacks.

Answer (score -2):

License keys are fairly useless in my honest opinion.
What's to stop your customer from distributing that key to others? Sure you could setup a license key server that records the number of activations but that costs money and what will happen if it goes down or goes away?

In my professional opinion, create a software that is branded uniquely to a user (encrypted inside the program of course). For example, if you goto help -> about of the software then display the person's name, phone, and possibly their address. This way if they upload it to a pirate site of some kind, not only will other people know this guys personal information...but so will you in order to charge him for more licenses or sue him.

Comment: I am able to take unique info out of the users technical environment that goes towards their key generation. So if anyone else intends to use it, the system does the check, halts and prompts for a valid key based on the new environment it is trying running in.

Yes, you can hack the most sophisticated licensing systems ever created. Microsoft have tried and failed and they have the dosh to throw at it to. But this is really a barrier to casual piracy. If someone really really wants to hack it they will..But this risk is fairly low considering what the software is for and the target market.